# I have to hit back button more than once to hit the back route in Backbone JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I have to hit back button more than once to hit the back route in Backbone JS. I tried to debug it using

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 

  return "You work will be lost.";
   };
```

But this function only gets called on refreshing the views. Let me know what could be the possible solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using for handle the click button ?

Comment: @rcarvalho :
 <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#promotions">

Comment: On clicking the above button I am routed to another backbone view .I have to press the back button of the browser more than once ,only then I am directed back to the previous view.